# Configuring Spring OAuth2 expression handler methods for authorization server endpoints using java config

Tags: java, spring, spring-security, spring-boot, spring-oauth2

In our app we would like to lock down the check_token endpoint so that only clients authenticated using client credentials can check the validity of tokens.

The documentation states that an expression handler is enabled by default when `@EnableResourceServer` is used, and has some instructions on how to set expression handling up using xml.
What do I need to do do have spring the evaluate the expression below using java config?

```
@Configuration
@EnableAuthorizationServer
public class OAuth2AuthorizationServerConfiguration extends AuthorizationServerConfigurerAdapter {

    ...

    @Override
    public void configure(AuthorizationServerSecurityConfigurer security) throws Exception {
        security.checkTokenAccess("#oauth2.isClient()");
    }

    ...
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The following isn't pretty, but it appears to work.

```
@EnableGlobalAuthentication
@Configuration
//@EnableAuthorizationServer
@Import({OAuth2AuthorizationServerConfiguration.SecurityConfiguration.class, AuthorizationServerEndpointsConfiguration.class})
public class OAuth2AuthorizationServerConfiguration extends AuthorizationServerConfigurerAdapter {


    @Configuration
    public static class SecurityConfiguration extends AuthorizationServerSecurityConfiguration {

        @Override
        protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
            http.authorizeRequests().expressionHandler(new OAuth2WebSecurityExpressionHandler());
            super.configure(http);
        }
    }
```

`AuthorizationServerSecurityConfiguration` provides access to the `HttpSecurity` object, which is where the expression handler needs to be inserted.

steps:

- subclass `AuthorizationServerSecurityConfiguration` and set the expression handler
- drop the `@EnableAuthorizationServer` annotation (because it also imports `AuthorizationServerSecurityConfiguration`)
- import the new subclass of `AuthorizationServerSecurityConfiguration`
- import `AuthorizationServerEndpointsConfiguration` (it was initially imported by `@EnableAuthorizationServer`